# Install Spideroak & keep Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud

I want to know if it is possible to install Spideroak and keep my Ubuntu One together. I love U1 but with Spideroak I get security and well another 2GB cloud space. Don't think I will be doing this because I have tons of space with U1 still, but think it is a question worth asking.

Can Spideroak and U1 work in harmony on the same machines? (Not even considering dropbox, but I guess the more I can find out the better.)

Comment: I've used them side-by-side, there's no issues preventing them from both working

Comment: I ran them side by side for a couple of days on 2 computers then did the 14.04 upgrade and let U1 disappear.  I have the "Ubuntu One" folder backed up and synced on 3 computers so it is the same for me today as it was when I actually had U1 (which I have removed from all computers since it is being discontinued as of Spring 2014).  If you are still undecided you can check out options at http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/what-are-your-plans-to-replace-ubuntu-one-and-why/1598

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they can run side-by-side without conflict.